# javascript can define callee after the caller, how it get parsed?

Tags: javascript

I wonder that how javascript can do it? The function can be defined after the caller calls the function.

Is there any document to explain how it works in detail?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats because of function declaration hoisting. All function declarations are hoisted to the top of the containing scope. A function declaration would look like:

```
function functionName(arg1, arg2){
    ..code here
}
```

And this is the reason you can call the function before it's actually been declared in your code.

But note that function expressions are not hoisted. So following is not hoisted:

```
var functionName = function(arg1, arg2){
    ..code here
};
```

So following would throw error:

```
functionName(); //TypeError, undefined is not a function!
var functionName = function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1);
};
```

**Added::**
Consider an example of function expressions::

```
saySomething(); //You get error here
var saySomething = function() {
    console.log("Hi there!");
};
```

This will not work and throw error, because , variable declarations and function declarations are hoisted, but in above example of function expression,  its variable declaration and assignment. The variable declaration gets hoisted but the assignment remains where it is. So the result would be like:

```
var saySomething;
saySomething(); //you get error here, which should be clear now as why you get the error
saySomething = function() {
    console.log("Hi there!");
};
```

Comment: To pedantic, the `var functionName` is hoisted but the `functionName = function...` assignment is not.

Comment: okay, so var functionName = function(arg1, arg2){ }; will work normally, right?

Answer (score 3):

It's called 'hoisting'. This article explains it very well: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Basically what is happening is the first code snippet gets treated as if it were the second:

```
a();
function a(){};
```

becomes

```
var a = function a(){};
a();
```

Comment: While your answer is a good explanation, your second snippet is incorrect.  You need to drop the `var a =` part, because that would be a function expression, which is quite different than the function declaration in the first snippet.  Simply swapping the lines of the first snippet is good enough of an example to describe hoisting.